Custom logs message in gtag.js
On checkout, I suddenly saw this message on my console, and it made me worried. When I looked it up, it was coming from the gtag.js file. Is it okay for this kind of log in the console, or should I contact support?
Here are the screenshots which I took. One is console logs and the other is the javascript which is loaded through Google Tag Manager.



Quite a few are seeing it, including me.
It seems to be some debug code accidentally added to the production gtag. It'll probably disappear soon.
